# LSTM (M or num_units) Explanation

Tags: lstm

So I am not able to understand what is M or nun units when we code an LSTM, we input a T*D matrix output is T*M if we have the return sequences =True.

for ex: x = LSTM(15, return_sequences=True)(x)
**is this value 15 number of hidden states in a single LSTM cell or this means 15 LSTM cells stacked at a given time stamp**

Comment: The former. One LSTM layer with units or number of states as 15.

Answer (score 0):

num_units is the number of hidden states within a LSTM cell not the number of LSTM cells

A LSTM Layer -> model.add(LSTM(num_unit, input_sequence))
consists of LSTM cells equivalent to your specified input_sequence